# Golang improper JSON unmarshal

Tags: json, go

Why this code shows improper output

http://play.golang.org/p/NBYnJOhmV2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to parse JSON into a structure, the members must be public - ie have an initial Capital.

Eg

```
type Base struct {
    Results []struct {
        Mp_id                   string
        First_name              string
        Last_name               string
    }
    Count int
    Page  struct {
        Count    int
        Per_page int
        Page     int
    }
}
```

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/E8PzeZWTfi)